# How to autoplay video in phaser?

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I try to play video automatically in phaser. But when video start, there is a message "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." in console.

Yes, I read https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes and know that muted video can play automatically but I want to play unmuted video automatically. How to play unmuted video automatically in phaser?

Answer (score 1):

I find answer for myself.

```
    game.add.video('chrome', 'assets/video/chrome.webm');
    chrome.video.autoplay = true;
```

I played phaser video automatically in that way.